# How to control distance between formulas with align?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I have the following code

```
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^0(t) &= \frac{t}{T}\begin{bmatrix}
    d \\
    \pi \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
,&
u^0(t) = 0
\end{align*}
```

which results in 
[image]

but I need something more like that
[image]

Comment: There is no real reason for using `align` here but you can just replace `,&
u^0(t) = 0` by `,\qquad
u^0(t) = 0` to get what you want.

Comment: `align` isn't designed to be used for a single-line equation.  So `equation` is what should be used here, with explicit spacing.  (As commented already, `\qquad` is a good size.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mis-use of the `align` environment to employ it for typesetting a pair of equations that are placed on one line.

I'd just separate the equations by `\qquad`, get rid of the `&` symbols, and replace `\begin{align*}` with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{align}` with `\end{equation}`.

The following code also places the equation number on the left rather than on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{6}  % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{15}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}^0(t) = \frac{t}{T}\begin{bmatrix}
    d \\ \pi \\ 0 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
u^0(t) = 0\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The example in the question has an equation number, so you want `equation`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. I'd gone more with the OP's code than with the screenshot. Will update my answer.